# Display hover effect but ignore click event?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a basic structure like this

```
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.click-layer {
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.2);
  pointer-events: auto;
}



function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <canvas
        className="click-layer"
        onClick={() => console.log("Click on Layer 1")}
      >
      </canvas>
      <div className="box" onClick={() => console.log("Click on box")}>
        Box
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I would like to have a hover effect when the user hovers over the **box**. For example, the background-color should change to 'red'.

But click events will be ignored since I want the **.click-layer** to receive those events.

Is there any way I could implement this? Thanks in advance!

**Expected behavior**

- Hover in the box => background-color change to red
- Click on the box => The console log "Click on layer 1"

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <canvas
        className="click-layer"
        onClick={() => console.log("Click on Layer 1")}
      >
        Layer 1
      </canvas>
      <div className="box" onClick={() => console.log("Click on box")}>
        Box
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.click-layer {
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.2);
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: red;
 /* pointer-events: none; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Is the click event for touch devices only?

Comment: no. for all devices

Comment: Why do you want to have an onClick event on a box? You can just remove it or help me to understand your question.

Comment: @Subro I can remove it of course, but the click-layer still does not get the click events if the box is clicked

Comment: Your question is how to not change BG color onClick?

Comment: My question is I want to keep bg change, but ignore onClick events in the box.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving the onClick event to your `.click-layer` and `.box`, you can give it to the whole `.container` class. If you select any one of them, it will console it out. I hope that this is what you expected.

```
<div className="container" onClick={() => console.log("Click on Container")}>
  <div className="click-layer">Layer 1 </div>
  <div className="box">
    Box
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container" onClick={() => console.log("Click on Container")}>
      <div className="click-layer">Layer 1 </div>
      <div className="box">
        Box
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.click-layer {
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.2);
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: red;
  /* pointer-events: none; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: About the result, that's what I want. But unfortunately, I want to receive the click events on '.click-layer' not the parent :/

Comment: Sorry, It is very confusing. You want to change the bg color of the box and don't want to have onclick event when it hovers. If so you can remove the onClick event from the box. You were also saying that you also want to receive the click event of `.click-layer` when it is clicked. For that, you have correctly set up the JSX.